# Data pointer has changed when received in the callback

Tags: c, linux, list, gtk

I have a list store treeview. Clicking an item of that calls "replace_tab" and adds a back button to display. Clicking the back button calls Back.Back. The handler is passed an instance of pointer to a list. I have printed the value of pointer both before and after the back handler is called.

```
struct BTDeviceDetails
{
    char*addr;
    char*name;
};

struct node
{
    struct node* next;
    struct BTDeviceDetails * data;
};

struct param
{
    GtkWidget* backbutton;
    GtkWidget* Okbutton;
    GtkWidget* scrolledwindow;
    GtkWidget*newChild;
    GtkWidget*oldChild;
    struct node** start;
};

static void Back (GtkButton *button, gpointer   user_data)
{
      struct param* parameters = (struct param*)user_data;
      printf("\nreplacetab=%p\n",(void*)*(parameters->start)); // prints-> "replacetab=0x7fffcd8b1320"
      ............
}

static void replace_tab(GtkTreeView *tree_view, GtkTreePath *path, GtkTreeViewColumn *column, gpointer user_data)
{
    struct node * start = 0;
      deviceDiscovery(&start);
    .............
    parameters->start = &start;
    printf("\n replacetab=%p \n",(void*)*(parameters->start)); // prints-> "replacetab=(nil)"
    g_signal_connect(parameters->newChild,"row-activated", G_CALLBACK( registerDevice ) ,&start);
    g_signal_connect(parameters->backbutton, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(Back), (gpointer) parameters);
}

int main()
{
    ....................
    g_signal_connect(treeview, "row-activated", G_CALLBACK(replace_tab), (gpointer) parameters);
    ....................
}
```

Comment: You've removed too much code, so it's hard to figure out what you're really doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that `parameters->start = &start;` can't work outside of that fuction. You're supposed to either allocate some memory through `g_new0` or `g_malloc` and have it filled by `deviceDiscovery`, or `deviceDiscovery` is supposed to return you an allocated node. As it takes a `node **`, it's more likely that's the second option.

Then in your parameters, don't store a `node **start`, you only need the content, not where it is stored I suppose, so `node *start` should be enough. Then you'll be able to just write:

```
struct node *start = NULL;
deviceDiscovery(&start); // Allocates structure memory and initializes it
// You may want to check if start != NULL to avoid errors later.
parameters->start = start;
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem fixed by making start as static variable
static struct node* start = 0;

Comment: This is most likely a bad idea. It works on the short term, but makes your code more fragile.